# Which is a better Firestore schema scenario?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, schema

I am building an application with Firebase Firestore that will allow user's the ability to open a tab at a bar. There are two database schemas I could potentially use. I'm curious which one would be best taking into account time complexity on `where()` queries, as well as any other pieces of advice.

**Scenario A:**

Set up Firestore with one `Bills` collection. Whenever a user opens a tab at a bar, create a document with a field `status: true` in the document (signaling it's an open tab). Whenever the user closes the tab, that field gets switched to `status: false`. This is a very simple solution as it allows for only the switching of one field whenever the tab is closed, although the `Bills` collection could become very large and potentially cumbersome for Firestore to query later.

**Scenario B:**

Set up Firestore with two collections: `Open Bills` & `Closed Bills`. Whenever a user opens a tab, a document gets created under the `Open Bills` collection. As you might expect, whenever a user closes their bill it gets deleted from `Open Bills` and created in `Closed Bills`. It's essentially like it's moved from one to another, but there's unfortunately no move functionality in Firestore. This is the solution I'm leaning towards because if it were to scale it could potentially cut down on query time, but introduces potential failures when it comes to the write and delete operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries scale with the size of the result set. If you return 100 results, a query of a collection of 1,000 documents will take about the same as one with 10,000,000 documents.

Without knowing more details, Option A seems like a perfectly reasonable approach. One thing I'd recommend: don't use a boolean for state. Right now you think you have two states (open/closed), but what if down the road there's more (open/closed/paid)?

Perhaps a `state` field that can be `open` | `closed` for now would be a way to go.